# How to access (local) mysql database with python on amazon ubuntu linux

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

So I just set-up an ubuntu server on amazon and installed mysql. It is working with:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

And then the mysql_password. I have added via command line a database and tables. But now I wonder how I can access this database with python locally (and eventually remotely).

If I try locally something like:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="mysql_password", db="dbname")
```

I get the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'dbname'")
```

However, the database dbname does exist at /var/lib/mysql. So how to access this via python (first locally and eventually remotely)?

Comment: What happens when you connect via the command line, and type `USE dbname;`?

Comment: If you're connecting to the instance that's remote, from your local computer, then you need to put the public IP address/hostname from the AWS dashboard for  your instance as the host. I suspect you have MySQL installed locally and you're connecting to that, but don't have the dbname database created there.

Comment: @FrankerZ I get:
mysql> USE dbname
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

Comment: @flip I get all that, but I'm accessing it on the server. So I am on the same machine where my database is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, it was a spelling mistake in dbname